# What is the meaning of this for(i--;i>j;j+=2,i-=j%3)?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iterator, integer

```
int i =14;
int j =2;
    for(i--;i>j;j+=2,i-=j%3){
        System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

It returns 13,12,12,10 but I don't understand the reason behind it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get familiar with the for loop  First part initates the counter of the for loop normaly. Second part defines the condition to enter the loop for another round, third part updates  the counter for the next round.

1. Starting the for loop i is set to 13 by i--.

   - 13 is greater than 2.
   - Therefore print i = 13.
   - Update counters j = 4 by j+=2 and i= 12 by i-=4%3 alias i-=1.
2. Condition 12 is greater than 4 passed.

   - Therefore print i = 12.
   - Update counters j = 6 by j+=2 and i= 12 by i-=6%3 alias i-=0
3. Condition 12 is greater than 6 passed.

   - Therefore print i = 12.
   - Update counters j = 8 by j+=2 and i= 10 by i-=8%3 alias i-=2
4. Condition 10 is greater than 8 passed.

   - Therefore print i = 10.
   - Update counters j = 10 by j+=2 and i= 9 by i-=10%3 alias i-=1
5. Condition 9 is greater than 10 failed.

   - Exit the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're familiar with while loop. Your code is same as below code:

```
int i = 14;
int j = 2;

i -= 1;
while(i > j) {
    System.out.println(i + " ");
    j += 2;
    i -= j % 3;
}
```

Refer [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more information on `for` loops.

syntax of `for` loops:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

You can provide multiple initialization, termination or increment. In your code you have provided multiple expressions for increment.

You can analyze your code, especially loops, by creating a table as shown below. You can create a table, where rows will represent iterations and columns will represent the expressions with their execution order starting from left:

| i | j | i > j | System.out.println(i + " "); | j += 2 | i -= j % 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2 | true | 13 | 4 | 12 |
| 12 | 4 | true | 12 | 6 | 12 |
| 12 | 6 | true | 12 | 8 | 10 |
| 10 | 8 | true | 10 | 10 | 9 |
| 9 | 10 | false |  |  |  |

Comment: Nit: `i -= 1;` is more similar to `--i;` than `i--;`. It doesn't really matter if you're not using the value of the expression; but since you've used "the same thing" for all of the other expressions, I'd stick with `i--` as in the original.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is reduced to 13 as the starting condition. `i>j` is the condition for continued looping, so if `j>=i` the loop exits. On each iteration, `j` is increased by 2 and `i` is decreased by `j%3` (this is the remainder after `j` is divided by 3).

I suggest that on paper you manually calculate `i` and `j` to satisfy yourself of this outcome.